# Google Calendar

Tags: php, mysql, google-calendar-api

I have been messing about with google calendars and I think they have a good look and feel, so I *MIGHT* add one to my website.

I just have some questions before I do.

1. Can I set up the calendar to populate from a MYSQL datasource using PHP on my page?
2. Does the calendar have to use an iframe?
3. Can I force the calendar to use my Style Sheet?
4. Are there better solutions to google calendar?

Any links and pointers appreciated.

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to question #4, yes I think: 
http://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar

You can put data in it with Json :-)